# PHP search a string from an array for match using preg_filter

Tags: php, arrays

I am search the year `2018` from `$data` array.
It will return the value `Jan`.

I need to display `Jan 2018`

**Sample Code**

```
$data = Array(
    '2017-08' => 'Aug 2017',
    '2017-09' => 'Sep 2017',
    '2017-10' => 'Oct 2017',
    '2017-11' => 'Nov 2017',
    '2017-12' => 'Dec 2017',
    '2018-01' => 'Jan 2018'
);
$input = preg_quote('2018', '~');
$result = preg_filter('~' . $input . '~', false, $data);
print_r($result);
```

**Auctual Output**

```
Array
(
    [2018-01] => Jan 
)
```

**Expected Output**

```
Array
(
    [2018-01] => Jan 2018
)
```

Please Advise!

Comment: By the way, your example is for `$input = preg_quote('2018', '~');`, not `$input = preg_quote('2017', '~');` as you quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_filter` works as a [search and replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php) function, so you're simply replacing the found  "2018" with nothing. Maybe you were more looking for something like [preg-grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)?